# Magento 1.9.1.0 - products not showing after changing data in product details fields

Tags: magento, visibility, product

My task was to change existing products in shop with new one, so all that i have changed is **NAME**, 
**SKU**, and **URL key** in **GENERAL** section and description field in **PRODUCT DETAILS**.
After i have done that, items are successfully edited in backend but they dissapear from frontend.
The only way to get to them in frontend is to enter complete address of that specific product in the address bar.
I have tried everything that i could found on the forum up to this date, and it didn't work for me.
Tips like reindexing, status - enabled, availability - in stock...
If someone has an idea, please, share it with me.
Thank you all.

Comment: Have you reindexed after the changes?

Comment: Yes, i did. I have mentioned that in post.

Comment: If you search product using sku and go to product page.The product page url is same before change or changed after the changes?

Comment: Now the url is a new one, that i have typed and saved.

Comment: I think the urls have been changes as you changes the names for the products.

Comment: Well "url-key" is tightly binded to the product so if that is changed then all the product url-rewrites are lost(so product links don't work on frontend) which can't be restored even after re-indexing multiple times. Product list page shows products right ?

Comment: Now i've seen previous answear. Products are visible only in backend, and nowhere in frontend.

Comment: Yes, as I said, changing "url-key" creates issue in url-rewrites and so product links will give "404 not found" error when redirecting to product page. Is product-list page showing list properly just like before ?

Comment: As i said. In frontend, products can't be seen, unless i type exact url to that specific product. And in magento backend, every product is on the list when i click on that category in manage products category.

Comment: No I am asking about product-list page in frontend, like when you click on category does it lists-out all it's products in frontend ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for my problem was in associated products section. I had configurable product, but i didn't had associated (simple product) for that configurable product. So i had to create some simple product for related configurable, and then they appeared in frontend.
Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below things:

```
1. Check the product quantity,in stock and enable status and catalog visibility.
2. Re indexing
3. delete the entry from url rewrite management for your product
4. rename the "var" folder
```